# Return row(s) when no values are found in the query

Tags: t-sql, null, records

I have a table `MyTable` that is populated by BizTalk from two outside agencies (`AGC1` and `AGC2`) every day. I have recently run into a problem where `AGC2` has been sending a blank file, so no records get updated.

I need to run a query like below, that would return

```
AGC1   01/28/2016
AGC2   NULL
```

But since I have no records for `AGC2` I only get

```
AGC1   01/28/2016
```

How can I get `AGC2 NULL` as in the first resultset?

```
SELECT Agency, MAX(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), DATEENTERED, 101)), Case when MAX(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), DATEENTERED, 101)) = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 101) THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' end
FROM DBO.MYTABLE 
GROUP BY AGENCY
```

Answer (score 1):

Have another table containing:

NameTable

```
Name
-----
AGC1
AGC2
```

Then use this query:

```
Select n.Name, max(m.dateentered)
from MyTable m right join NameTable n
on m.Agency = n.Name
group by n.Name
```

Comment: nope i am still only getting AGC1 NULL  because AGC2 is not in mytable at all.

Answer (score 0):

A `RIGHT JOIN` with a table containing all agencies should do the trick. This version uses a derived table with `VALUES`:

```
SELECT 
    ag.Agency, 
    MAX(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), mt.DATEENTERED, 101)), 
    Case when MAX(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), mt.DATEENTERED, 101)) = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 101) THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' end
FROM 
    DBO.MYTABLE AS mt
    RIGHT JOIN ( VALUES('AGC1'),('AGC2') ) AS ag(Agency) ON
         ag.Agency=mt.Agency
GROUP BY
    ag.AGENCY
```